# Storing Arraylist<Double> into Realm database

Tags: android, database, realm

Is it possible to store `ArrayList<Double>` into Realm database, and has anyone an example ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Realm documentation : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#inverse-relationships

> Realm model classes can contains lists of primitive data types. This must be modeled using RealmList, where T can be the following types: String, Integer, Boolean, Float, Double, Short, Long, Byte, byte[] and Date.

You have to use `RealmList` to store lists in Realm :

```
public RealmList<String> myProp = new RealmList<>();
```